# drop rows of specific time

Tags: python, pandas

```
    Date              Open        High         Low        Close  Volume 
2022-08-08 09:15:00 17397.39    17443.70    17359.75    17411.06    0   
2022-08-10 13:15:00 17508.28    17532.00    17479.55    17510.24    0   
2022-08-12 09:15:00 17651.81    17680.70    17597.85    17654.14    0   
2022-08-18 09:15:00 17934.37    17954.65    17863.45    17914.30    0
```

I have this dataframe . I have to drop the rows when time= 9:15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `~` operator to negate the conditions:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df[~((df.Date.dt.hour == 9) & (df.Date.dt.minute == 15))]
```